# Error creating bean with name .. Injection of autowired dependencies failed

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-ws

im implementing a java spring client to access the webservice, but im having problem with bean creation and autowire. im not sure what are those because im very new to these. im not using maven, just pure eclipse for javaEE (if that matters, cause the example i followed @ [here](http://ankeetmaini.wordpress.com/2011/12/01/spring-web-services-client/%20uses%20maven%29) uses maven). sorry for the long piece of codes, im stuck..

i have a ClientController.java in package com.helloworld.controller

```
package com.helloworld.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate;

import com.helloworld.domain.*;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ClientController {
    @Autowired
     private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

     /**
     * This is the default handler. When application goes live
     * the control comes to this, and it fires a JSP,
     * asking the input.
     */
     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public String getRequest(Model model) {
     model.addAttribute("HelloWorldRequest", new ObjectFactory().createHelloWorldRequest());
     //Show request.jsp
     return "request";
     }

     /**
     * This is the handler, which takes in the input number, and calculates
     * the square by taking it from the webservice, via WebServiceTemplate, and then finally
     * sets as a ModelAttribute, which in turn is shown by "response.jsp"
     */
     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public String showResponse(@ModelAttribute HelloWorldRequest helloWorldRequest, Model model) {
     //Creating the SquareServiceResponse object.
     HelloWorldResponse helloWorldResponse = new ObjectFactory().createHelloWorldResponse();
     //Sending the request object via WebServiceTemplate and getting back the response from WebService <img src="http://s0.wp.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_smile.gif?m=1129645325g" alt=":)" class="wp-smiley"> 
     helloWorldResponse = (HelloWorldResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(helloWorldRequest);
     //This was supposed to be a hard part. Piece of cake <img src="http://s0.wp.com/wp-includes/images/smilies/icon_smile.gif?m=1129645325g" alt=":)" class="wp-smiley"> 
     model.addAttribute("helloWorldResponse",helloWorldResponse);
     //Show response.jsp
     return "response";
     }
}
```

in my package com.helloworld.domain, i have the following files:

```
HelloWorldRequest.java
HelloWorldResponse.java
ObjectFactory.java
package-info.java
```

in my WEB-INF, i have views directory which has request and respond.jsp. in the root of WEB-INF, i have spring-ws-client-servlet.xml and web.xml.

spring-ws-client-servlet.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

 <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
 <context:annotation-config />

<!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered
 as Spring beans. For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the
 correct base-package -->
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.helloworld.domain" />
 <context:component-scan base-package="com.helloworld.controller" />

<!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming
 model. Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only! -->
 <mvc:annotation-driven />
 <!-- Declare a view resolver -->
 <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" p:prefix="/WEB-INF/views/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

 <bean id="webServiceTemplate" class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate" p:marshaller-ref="jaxbMarshaller" p:unmarshaller-ref="jaxbMarshaller"
 p:defaultUri="http://localhost:8080/HelloWorld/HelloWorldService"
 p:messageSender-ref="messageSender">
 <constructor-arg ref="messageFactory"/>
 </bean>
 <bean id="messageSender" class="org.springframework.ws.transport.http.CommonsHttpMessageSender"/>
 <bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory"/>
 <bean id="jaxbMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller"
 p:contextPath="com.helloworld.domain"/>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
 <display-name>HelloWorld Web Application</display-name>
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>spring-ws-client</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>spring-ws-client</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The errors im getting are:

```
SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate com.helloworld.controller.ClientController.webServiceTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webServiceTemplatez' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-client-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/URI
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate com.helloworld.controller.ClientController.webServiceTemplate; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webServiceTemplatez' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-client-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/URI
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'webServiceTemplatez' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-ws-client-servlet.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/URI
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:532)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/URI
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2398)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1838)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:978)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:951)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    ... 58 more
May 2, 2013 11:10:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext loadOnStartup
SEVERE: Servlet /HelloWorldClient threw load() exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.httpclient.URI
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1713)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2398)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:1838)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:978)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:951)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:107)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1393)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1122)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:651)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:599)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:665)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:518)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1280)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

request.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ page session="false" %>

<html>
<head>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<title>Square Webservice 2 Client</title>
</head>
<body>
 <form:form commandName="helloWorldRequest" method="post">
 <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Get Hello!" />
 </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

response.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
 pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<html>
<head>
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>
<title>Square Webservice 2 Client</title>
</head>
<body>
 The hello value is: <b><font color="red" size="3">${helloWorldResponse.output}</font></b>
 <br />
</body>
</html>
```

list of jars added in /WEB-INF/lib:

```
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.2-javadoc.jar
commons-logging-1.1.2-sources.jar
commons-logging-1.1.2-test-sources.jar
commons-logging-1.1.2-tests.jar
commons-logging-1.1.2.jar
commons-logging-adapters-1.1.2.jar
commons-logging-api-1.1.2.jar
commons-logging-tests.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
pdfbox-app-1.8.1.jar
spring-aop-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-aop-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-aop-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-aspects-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-aspects-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-beans-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-build-src-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-context-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-context-support-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-context-support-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-core-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-expression-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-expression-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-instrument-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-instrument-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-instrument-tomcat-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-jdbc-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-jdbc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-jms-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-jms-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-orm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-oxm-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-oxm-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-struts-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-struts-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-struts-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-test-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-test-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-test-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-tx-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-tx-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-web-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-webmvc-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-3.2.2.RELEASE-javadoc.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-3.2.2.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-webmvc-portlet-3.2.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-ws-2.1.3.RELEASE-all.jar
spring-ws-2.1.3.RELEASE-sources.jar
spring-ws-core-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-ws-security-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-ws-support-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-xml-2.1.3.RELEASE.jar
wsdl4j.jar
```

Comment: you need httpClient jar -> *Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/httpclient/URI*

Answer (score 0):

You're missing apache commons witch is dependency of Spring.
You can download it from here and add it to the classpath of your project http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/download_lang.cgi
Also consider using Maven.

Comment: hi, i have commons-lang.. let me update my post, listing the jars i have in WEB-INF/libs